# Discord Gateway - receive new messages in channel alerts (GUILD_MESSAGES MESSAGE_CREATE?) without a bot connected to the server

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, bots, discord-jda

There is a discord server which has a channel with a lot of messages coming in. I am interested only in fraction of them and I want to make an application which will filter new messages using a keyword and notify me when a new message which interests me was posted.

From what I know, you can only use Gateway part of Discord Developer Tools with a bot connected to a server. I doubt the server owner will allow my bot there due to population of the server.

Is there some way I could achieve my goal of using Gateway? If not, is using:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages
my only other option?

Comment: If the server owner won't allow a bot from you, what makes you think they want you to run some automation without a bot? Clearly, the server owner doesn't want you to run any kind of automation there at all. It would also be against the discord terms of service to run any automation on a non-bot account.

Comment: "Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found." I want to use it inside of OAuth2 though, so it's not against ToS

Answer (score 0):

No. You need explicit permissions to view the contents of a server. You cannot do that via Gateway, that would expose all messages ever written to everyone.

Your bot / application needs to be part of the server. You can simply take a look a the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) reference to see the difference between [`fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) (API call) vs [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel).

Comment: What if I am (as an user, not a bot), a member of this server?

Comment: @SSV Doesn't matter. The bot itself must be a member of the server.